# Creating dictionary with map & filter?

Tags: javascript, csv, dictionary, d3.js

I have the following map and filter functions in order to get my csv file data *with their column names as keys*.

```
d3.csv("Sales Export Friendly 3-19-17.csv", function(data) {
    sales = data
        .map(sale => [
        sale["Unit Booked"],
        new Date(sale["Booking Date"]).getMonth() + 1,
        new Date(sale["Checkin"]).getMonth() + 1,
        (new Date(sale["Checkout"]).valueOf() - new Date(sale["Checkin"]).valueOf())/(24*60*60*1000),
        +sale["Total Stay"],
        (+sale["Total Stay"]) / ((new Date(sale["Checkout"]).valueOf() - new Date(sale["Checkin"]).valueOf())/(24*60*60*1000)),
        ])
        .filter(([unit, date, checkin, LOS, total, avgNight]) => !isNaN(total));
```

This works for most purposes but I haven't figured out how to retain the column names to reference them as axes in a d3 multidimensional type of viz (parallel coordinates). I think it may have to do with the use of map and filter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you load a CSV file, `d3.csv` creates a handy array property called `columns`.

According to the [API](https://github.com/d3/d3-dsv/blob/master/README.md#dsv_parse):

> The returned array also exposes a `columns` property containing the column names in input order (in contrast to Object.keys, whose iteration order is arbitrary).

Thus, since your callback parameter is named `data`, you can get the columns' names simply using:

```
data.columns
```

Or assigning it to a variable:

```
var myColumns = data.columns
```

Here is a demo with a real CSV file from this [Bostock's bl.ocks](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3887051):

```js
d3.csv("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/mbostock/3887051/raw/805adad40306cedf1a513c252ddd95e7c981885a/data.csv", function(data){
  console.log(data.columns);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

PS: this answer refers to D3 v4, which should be the **default** version for answers, unless stated otherwise in the question.

Comment: Thank you, this helped move me along. I do need some help parsing the date columns now if you can help there:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42990052/parsing-dates-using-time-in-d3