# parsing dates using time in d3

Tags: javascript, date, d3.js

How can I get something like this to work?

Example date format:

```
6/20/2016 10:30:00 AM
```

Example operation I want to perform:

```
parseDate(data["Checkin"]).getMonth() + 1
```

Current parseDate function:

```
var parseDate = d3.time.format("%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S %p").parse;
```

I am getting a data.slice is not a function TypeError when calling a d3 graphing function after the following:

```
var data = d3.csv("Sales Export Friendly 3-19-17.csv", function(data) {
    return {
        unit: data["Unit Booked"],
        date: parseDate(data["Booking Date"]).getMonth() + 1,
        checkin: parseDate(data["Checkin"]).getMonth() + 1,
        LOS: new Date(data["Checkout"]).valueOf() - new Date(data["Checkin"]).valueOf()/(24*60*60*1000),
        total: +data["Total Stay"],
        avgNight: (+data["Total Stay"]) / ((new Date(data["Checkout"]).valueOf() - new Date(data["Checkin"]).valueOf())/(24*60*60*1000)),
        }
```

Comment: Thank you. Fixed that and I'm still getting the same TypeError, which I've posted along with the relevant code above.

Comment: thank you; it's easy forget when I move from one SO question to another from a helpful answer

Comment: You probably have a problem with your data, because the code is working, look here: https://jsfiddle.net/gerardofurtado/xbxh0suz/

Comment: You're right. Does data.columns work for d3 v3? I am getting undefined. I forgot to mention that in my last question. Had to use v3 to get the par coords library working...

Comment: Posted a more complete question/example/error code over here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43009417/reading-in-csv-with-date-parsing