# reading in csv with date parsing

Tags: javascript, date, csv, d3.js

Having a very hard time loading in my data correctly. Here is the header row with the first content row:

```
BookingID,Type,Status,Unit Booked,Unit Owner,Destination,Booking Date,Checkin,Checkout,Renter - FirstName,Renter - LastName,Renter - EmailAddress,Renter - WorkPhone,Renter - HomePhone,#Adults,#Children,Total Stay,Total Paid,Total Due
15642889,House,Confirmed,GV T3 #2106,,,3/20/2016 7:00:00 PM,3/23/2016 3:00:00 PM,3/28/2016 11:00:00 AM,FirstName,LastName,first&last@gmail.com,+1 (000) 000-0000,+1 (000) 000-0000,2,0,895,895,0
```

And the relevant lines of loading in and parsing my csv as I want:

```
var parseDate = d3.time.format("%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S %p").parse;
var data = d3.csv("Sales Export Friendly 3-19-17.csv", function(data) {
    return {
        unit: data["Unit Booked"],
        date: parseDate(data["Booking Date"]).getMonth() + 1,
        checkin: parseDate(data["Checkin"]).getMonth() + 1,
        LOS: parseDate(data["Checkout"]).valueOf() - parseDate(data["Checkin"]).valueOf()/(24*60*60*1000),
        total: +data["Total Stay"],
        avgNight: (+data["Total Stay"]) / ((new Date(data["Checkout"]).valueOf() - new Date(data["Checkin"]).valueOf())/(24*60*60*1000))
        };
});
```

The idea is that I will then do something like this:

```
d3.parcoords()("#TopLeft").alpha(0.4)
        .data(data)
        .dimensions(data.columns)
```

If I try to console.log(data.columns); after my callback function, I get undefined. Here is what console.log(data); prints, which is quite odd looking:

```
Object { header: Cn/u.header(), mimeType: Cn/u.mimeType(), responseType: Cn/u.responseType(), response: Cn/u.response(), get: Cn/</u[n](), post: Cn/</u[n](), send: Cn/u.send(), abort: Cn/u.abort(), on: M/<(), row: e/o.row() }
```

And the error codes I am currently getting:

```
TypeError: data.slice is not a function
```

When calling data(data) on d3.parcoords and

```
TypeError: e is undefined
```

On this line:

```
checkin: parseDate(data["Checkin"]).getMonth() + 1,
```

I am terribly confused as to what is going wrong here. I am using d3 v3.

Comment: I have not used D3's csv parser (although I use D3 otherwise). However, if you are using version 3, it seems like your data results actually come, as complete array, as a second callback, not as a return result. The only callback you have defined is the accessor. See the [documentation on it](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/CSV.md#csv)

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: I am wrong. The callback is per row. However, the data are indeed loaded asynchronously in the newest version of d3. I had some trouble finding the right way to use this function, but I found the solution. d3.csv now returns a promise. To use the parsed data, pass doSomething to the `promise.then()`.

Original comment, for context:

> The CSV file is loaded asynchronously, so setting
>   data=d3.csv(path,callback) makes little sense. When you declare a
>   callback, that is where things must happen. The callback may refer to
>   a global variable, or just use a local variable and pass the result to
>   the next stage. Judging by your code, you want to output an object
>   that holds filtered/postprocessed columns stored under their
>   respective keys.
>
> Also, I doubt that the time parse method can be applied to an array.
>   To do that, you likely have to use array.map.
>
> I would suggest something like this (not tested):
>
> ```
> var parseDate = d3.time.format("%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S %p").parse;
> d3.csv("Sales Export Friendly 3-19-17.csv", function(data) {
>     //Note that data is a local in this function scope
>     let filtered_data = {
>         unit: data["Unit Booked"],
>         date: data["Booking Date"].map(s=>parseDate().getMonth()+1),
>         checkin: data["Checkin"].map(s=>parseDate().getMonth()+1),
>         total: data["Total Stay"].map(s=>+s),
>     };
>
>     filtered_data.LOS = [];
>     filtered_data.avgNight = [];
>     let N = data["Checkout"].length;
>     for (let i=0; i < N; i++) {
>         filtered_data.LOS[i] = parseDate(data["Checkout"][i]).valueOf() -parseDate(data["Checkin"][i]).valueOf()/(24*60*60*1000),
>         filtered_data.avgNight[i] = (+data["Total Stay"][i])/filtered_data.LOS[i];
>     }
>     doSomething(filtered_data);
> });
> ```

Comment: You are not wrong, this is the correct answer! The failure to correctly handle the asynchronous loading was the main issue of the question. You should definitely roll back your last edit and just correct the your original post. In fact, the edit is wrong as OP uses v3 which did not return a Promise. Again, stick with your first post and improve that version.

Comment: @altocumulus Thank you. I encourage you to edit my answer, since you obviously know this better than I do. :-)