# TypeError: data.slice is not a function Loading csv d3 issue

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js

```
var sales = d3.csv("Sales Export Friendly 3-19-17.csv", function(error, data) {
    //var parseDate = d3.time.format("%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S %p").parse;
    return {
        unit: data["Unit Booked"],
        date: new Date(data["Booking Date"]).getMonth() + 1,
        checkin: new Date(data["Checkin"]).getMonth() + 1,
        LOS: new Date(data["Checkout"]).valueOf() - new Date(data["Checkin"]).valueOf()/(24*60*60*1000),
        total: +data["Total Stay"],
        avgNight: (+data["Total Stay"]) / ((new Date(data["Checkout"]).valueOf() - new Date(data["Checkin"]).valueOf())/(24*60*60*1000))
        }
});

console.log(sales);
console.log(d3.keys(sales[0]));


parcoords = d3.parcoords()("#TopLeft");

parcoords
```

the console logging statement on sales returns

```
Object { header: Cn/u.header(), mimeType: Cn/u.mimeType(), responseType: Cn/u.responseType(), response: Cn/u.response(), get: Cn/</u[n](), post: Cn/</u[n](), send: Cn/u.send(), abort: Cn/u.abort(), on: M/<(), row: e/o.row() }
```

I'm not sure how this weird object happened.

And the following console.log statement returns an empty array.

Last, I get a TypeError: data.slice is not a function when calling parcoords

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Until your [ante-penultimate question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42968428/5768908), you were doing it right:

```
d3.csv(url, function(data){
    //code here
});
```

Then, I don't know why, in your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43009417/5768908) (only now I'm noticing it) and in this question, you started doing this:

```
var data = d3.csv(url, function(data){
    //the rest of the code
```

Which will not work.

This is the problem: `d3.csv` **doesn't return** anything! Technically speaking, it returns an object related to the request (run the snippet to see it)...

```js
var test = d3.csv("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/mbostock/3887051/raw/805adad40306cedf1a513c252ddd95e7c981885a/data.csv", function(data){
});

console.log(test);
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

... which is not what you want.

Thus, change back to what you were doing...

```
d3.csv("Sales Export Friendly 3-19-17.csv", function(error, data) {
    //code here
})
```

... and drop that `var sales`.

Also, have in mind that `d3.csv` is **asynchronous**. So, you have to `console.log` your variables inside the callback:

```
d3.csv("Sales Export Friendly 3-19-17.csv", function(error, data) {
    console.log(data)//this works 
});

console.log(data)//this will not work
```

Comment: Hey thank you again, but I'm now getting a warning that I have code that is unreachable after my return statement. How can I fix this?

Comment: You have to post a minimum working version of your code, in a Plunker/CodePen/whatever...

Comment: hoping I got the formatting right... I do see the unreachable code after return error in the console, so it should be okay: https://jsfiddle.net/jw7wc650/3/

Comment: Well I put my return in a map function map and that seems to have solved my issues.